# Doctrine 2 Inheritance: GET method returns no data in abstract subclass

Tags: inheritance, symfony, doctrine-orm, abstract-class

I'm developing a web aplication with the framework Symfony2, that uses Doctrine 2 as ORM.

I have an abstract class called 'Pregunta' with five subclasses. One of them, an abstract class called 'Seleccion', has two subclasses: 'SelUnica' and 'SelMultiple'.

If I create an instance of 'SelUnica' or 'SelMultiple', their GET methods works correctly, but if I try to get an attribute of class 'Seleccion', the method returns no data, although in the database was succesfully saved. This only happens with the attributes, because the class 'Seleccion' has a relationship and GET works correctly.

The SET methods works correctly too and if I put an 'echo' inside the GET methods, it doesn't show any value.

Any idea?

The class codes:

http://pastebin.com/XurWLsst

Comment: As advised me @Gedrox, I changed the class 'Seleccion' to a MappedSuperclass, and after clear cache with Doctrine commands, still not working. The changed code is here: [http://pastebin.com/bc8tPd3q](http://pastebin.com/bc8tPd3q)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to mark the parent abstract classes with `@MappedSuperclass` annotation. See http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I have changed the class "Seleccion" to a MappedSuperclass but still not working. And I need that the superclass "Pregunta" has a discriminator column for recover the type of subclass of each instance of a collection.

Should I change the class "Pregunta" to a MappedSuperclass too? How I could do?

Comment: No, `Pregunta` is marked as entity, no need to define it as `@MappedSuperclass`. Haven't you got entity metadata cache defined which would cause the new configuration not being read?

Comment: I have tried to clear all the cache with this commands:

"app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata",

"app/console doctrine:cache:clear-query",

"app/console doctrine:cache:clear-result".

Still not working...